# How do I center a series of hrefs whilst allowing it to wrap

Tags: css, html

My simple footer code uses table of width 100% containing a centered td with another table within it containing the links, this centres the links in the availble space. Its work fine as long as there is enough horizontal space for all the links, but if there isn't (i.e on mobile phone, portait) it does not wrap. How can I keep centred but allow wrapping as necessary ?

```
<footer>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <nav>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="/reports">
                                    Reports
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="/preferences.go">
                                    Preferences
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="/about.go">
                                    About
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="/license.go">
                                    License
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="/admin.go">
                                    Admin
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="/webhelp/index_frames.html">
                                    Help
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </nav>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</footer>
```

Comment: Is a table required for your markup?

Comment: You shouldn't be using tables for layout, they are not responsive and hard to manage. Tables are used to display data.

Comment: @zgood yes i Know, but that was the only way I knew how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skip the table or just put the links all in a single td. They are inline and will wrap if necessary. Set `text-align:center` on the containing element to center the links.

```css
footer nav {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<footer>

  <nav>
    <a href="/reports">Reports</a>
    <a href="/preferences.go">Preferences</a>
    <a href="/about.go">About</a>
    <a href="/license.go">License</a>
    <a href="/admin.go">Admin</a>
    <a href="/webhelp/index_frames.html">Help</a>
  </nav>

</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks that centers the text whilst allowing wrapping, however I have no gap between my hrefs and it isn't my stylesheet since I have commented out all links to sytlesheets and the problems. Any idea why that would be, or what I shoud do compenate - nbsp; ?

Comment: I remember now that is why I had the internal table

Comment: &nbsp is really for things that shouldn't break at the space like `New&nbsp;York;` if you don't want it to wrap. If there is no space between the links, the container has font-size set to 0 but the links must have a font-size set since you can see them. Either set the font size on the container if you can, or add another wrapper-element around the links that you can set font-size on.  - maybe even the table that you started with but just put all of the links in one td. I know this makes people barf but it may fix it for you...

Comment: I dont have anything set on nav, but I added padding-right:4px to the a tags and that worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Flex if the table markup is not required

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a class="flex-item" href="/reports">
                                    Reports
                                </a>

    <a class="flex-item" href="/preferences.go">
                                    Preferences
                                </a>

    <a class="flex-item" href="/about.go">
                                    About
                                </a>

    <a class="flex-item" href="/license.go">
                                    License
                                </a>

    <a class="flex-item" href="/admin.go">
                                    Admin
                                </a>

    <a class="flex-item" href="/webhelp/index_frames.html">
                                    Help
                                </a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks but I went for the simpler answer in the end since I dont really understand flex

Comment: I don't either :) I always use this [cheat sheet](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)